# Android : Navigation Menu Item's Group Sequences

Tags: android, menu, android-navigation

I created a navigation menu XML file for my project.
**nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group
    android:id="@+id/group_note"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:icon="@drawable/all_notes"
        android:iconTint="@color/black1"
        android:title="Notes"/>
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/group_days"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <!-- all days will come here -->
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/group_setting"
    android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/setting"
        android:iconTint="@color/black1"
        android:title="Settings" >
    </item>
</group>
```

**group_days** item will dynamically. But the problem is,
*I except **group_days** after **group_note**. But it comes after **group_setting**!*
I don't know why.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is that all `items` that you added in `XML` have default order and that means next added `items` will go below already added items like you have in your scenario. Try to give an order to your items for example for `Notes` it will obviously be 0: `android:orderInCategory="0"` and for `Settings` try: `android:orderInCategory="2"` and then for each new added item set category to `1`. For example:

```
menu.add(R.id.monday, Menu.NONE, 1, "Monday");
menu.add(R.id.tuesday, Menu.NONE, 1, "Tuesday");
//and so on
```

Comment: For test first time I use `android:orderInCategory` into group. And it's working. Thank you friend.

Comment: I’m glad to hear you solve the problem. Your welcome